# High CPU usage with Hibernate FullTextQuery.list()

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cpu-usage, hibernate-search

First of all I'm pretty new to the Hibernate and I'm stuck with the problem for about a week or so. I can't find the solution by myself, so I have to ask for help here.

I'm trying to build simple location based API with the following stack:

1. Hibernate JPA (4.3.8) + Hibernate Search (5.1);
2. MySQL db with around 30000 of objects;
3. [Daoism project](https://github.com/bennidi/daoism);
4. Spring Framework for controlling db transactions;
5. Tomcat 7.

API is about finding terminals (ATMs) around you. I have three types of entities:

1. Terminal;
2. Transaction (not db transaction, but terminal transaction);
3. TransactionCurrency.

Every terminal has several transactions (one-to-many association). Transaction has several TransactionCurrencies (again, one-to-many association).

The problem is high cpu usage (60-80%) during searching Terminals.

Terminal entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="terminals",
    indexes = {
        @Index(name = "INDEX_terminals_id", columnList="id", unique = true)
})
@Indexed
@Spatial(name="distance", spatialMode = SpatialMode.HASH)
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Terminal implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    protected int id = 0;

    @Field
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    protected String name;

    @Field
    @Column(name = "owner", nullable = false)
    protected String owner;

    @Field
    @Column(name = "terminal_class", nullable = false)
    protected int terminalClass;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "terminal", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @OrderColumn(name="position")
    @IndexedEmbedded
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    protected List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<Transaction>();

    @Field
    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    protected String description;

    @Version
    private long version = -1;

    private Timestamp tsCreated = null;

    private Timestamp tsLastModified = null;

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist(){
        if (transactions != null && !transactions.isEmpty()) {
            for (Transaction t : transactions) {
                t.setTerminal(this);
            }
        }
        Timestamp now = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        if(tsCreated == null)tsCreated = now;
        tsLastModified = now;
    }

    public Terminal() {
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Here is the searching method of Terminal DAO:

```
public List<Terminal> getByParams(HashMap<String, Object> params) {


    List<Terminal> terminals = new ArrayList<Terminal>();
    List results = null;

    if (params != null && !params.isEmpty()) {

        EntityManager em = this.persistenceProvider.entityManager();
        Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);

        // create native Lucene query using the query DSL
        QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
                .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Terminal.class).get();

        BooleanJunction bj = qb.bool();

        Integer count = (Integer) params.get("count");
        Integer offset = (Integer) params.get("offset");
        Integer maxDist = (Integer) params.get("maxDist");
        Double gpsLatitude = (Double) params.get("gpsLatitude");
        Double gpsLongitude = (Double) params.get("gpsLongitude");

        if (count != null && offset != null && maxDist != null
                && count > 0 && offset >= 0 && maxDist > 0) {

            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                Object value = entry.getValue();

                if ((value != null && value instanceof Integer && (Integer) value > -1
                        && !key.equals("count") && !key.equals("offset") && !key.equals("maxDist")) ||
                        value != null && value instanceof String) {
                    bj.must(qb.keyword().onField(key).matching(value).createQuery());
                }
            }

            bj.must(qb.spatial()
                    .onField("distance")
                    .within(maxDist, Unit.KM)
                    .ofLatitude(gpsLatitude)
                    .andLongitude(gpsLongitude)
                    .createQuery());

            Query luceneQuery = bj.createQuery();

            FullTextQuery hibQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Terminal.class);
            Sort distanceSort = new Sort(
                    new DistanceSortField(gpsLatitude, gpsLongitude, "distance"));
            hibQuery.setSort(distanceSort);
            hibQuery.setProjection(FullTextQuery.SPATIAL_DISTANCE, FullTextQuery.THIS);
            hibQuery.setSpatialParameters(gpsLatitude, gpsLongitude, "distance");
            hibQuery.setFetchSize(count);
            hibQuery.setFirstResult(offset);
            hibQuery.setReadOnly(true);

            // execute search
            results = hibQuery.list();
            Iterator<Object[]> iterator = results.iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Object[] resultObject = iterator.next();
                if (resultObject.length == 2) {
                    double distanceInMeters = (Double) resultObject[0] * 1000;
                    Terminal terminal = (Terminal) resultObject[1];
                    terminal.setDistance(distanceInMeters);
                    terminals.add(terminal);
                }
            }

        } else {
            log.error("Empty param list passed to TerminalDAO class. Cannot find terminals.");
        }
    }

    return terminals;
}
```

I've used Apache Benchmark with 10 concurrent and 100 in total requests on the Core i7 2.5 Ghz with 16 Gb RAM (so hardware is fine):

```
ab -c 10 -n 100 "http://localhost:8080/getTerminals?class=1&lat=46.2317893&lon=50.168378&count=100"
```

As you can see the response contained 100 terminals near passed location. The queries were fast, but I'm worring about CPU usage.

According to the profiler, the most cpu intense method was FullTextQuery.list().

After reading hibernate docs and some research I've tried several things:

1. Use Eager/Lazy loading with collections;
2. turn off/on L2 cache;
3. setReadOnly(true) on FullTextQuery;
4. implement constructors with all properties.

but nothing helped.

Is it common problem for concurrent requests (selects from db)? Can Hibernate Search handle them? Am I missing something?

The full sample project can be found here: https://github.com/xvonabur/hib_debug

I appreciate any help.

Comment: There is something what is called Lucene search engine, will be helpful for you http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

Generally I would say this is expected, and usually people don't classify it as a problem but rather that you're putting your available CPUs to good use. "Unused CPU is a wasted CPU" as they say.

Hibernate Search relies on Apache Lucene, and this is extremely efficient on IO operations; developers work hard to make sure your CPUs won't have to wait for slow disks.

The scoring of queries is a computational intensive operation, so if you make multiple requests without any pause in between them, you'll be able to max out your CPU. Also consider a real benchmark should simulate user think pauses: you would still see spikes of CPU usage for when exactly a Query is performed, but these will be very short so the average CPU usage will be low.

Another benefit of this approach is the the application does most of the heavy lifting, so your MySQL database is getting only trivial tasks to perform; that's usually a good thing as you can scale your application on multiple nodes as needed; while it's usually harder to scale the database.

Still if you're interested in inspecting more, you could try using [Projections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#projections); by using projections you can completely avoid querying the database at all if you avoid loading 'THIS' but just take the fields you need, so you'll be able to inspect the performance of the fulltext query without the load-from-database aspect to confuse the figures.

Optimise them independently; of course options like 2nd level cache are meaningless when using just projections from the index. Taking the JDBC related code out of the picture should make it then easier to profile again and identify what else you could do. If you find any inefficiency in Hibernate Search, please open a [enter link description here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HSEARCH), we'll be very interested in your results.

Comment: Thanks, Sanne! So, in other words, 5% of cpu for single request (didn't mention it in original post) and 60-80% for 10 concurrent requests with 100 objects in response is normal behavior for Hibernate Search and Lucene. Am I right?

Comment: Unfortunately Projections is not the option for me, because I need all the Entity to return. I've tried to use vanilla Hibernate, but CPU usage was almost at the same level. If I try to get 1000 objects, the system will be 100% busy during several seconds.

Comment: No I don't expect the average CPU utilization to be significantly higher than with any other database query. What I said is that it's going to be normal to see a (very) short spike of CPU utilization when the Query is being performed. How high it actually looks to you is most probably a sampling problem, as tools will report the average. About Projections: right I understand it's not an option for your final product, but use them to identify performance issues as they will remove all of the RDBMs related operations. Just as a tool to help you profile better, temporarily.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the suggestion. My lucene index stores only ids of entities and everything else is in L2 cache. I'll try to use only projections for profiling.